# arctan2 transparency normalisation

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any simple way to create an arctan2 plot in python (matplotlib) which will have alpha channel or something like black/white colour? 
Imagine this as a full colour for maximum magnitude of generating arrays and transparent (or white/black) for the zero. Example of colourwheel with black for low magnitude:

[image: colour wheel with magnitude]

Comment: The question is unclear. Please plot an arctan2 in matplotlib with some usual colormap (e.g. "grey") and clearly state what should be different in order to fulfil your requirement.

Comment: by plotting arctan2 I only get angular information. I would like to get plot with magnitude information too - this is shown in color wheel as gradual change to black according to a norm: sqrt(x^2 + y^2)

Comment: Why don't you just [edit] your question to conform to [ask], clearly stating what you want to achieve and which problems you have in doing so?